# Javascript: Create Date object from a string with a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, antd

### Project setup

- Django and Django REST Framework on the backend
- React and AntD on the frontend

### Problem

I have a `DateField` and `TimeField` fields in my backend that return a string with format "YYYY-MM-DD" and "HH:mm:ss" respectively. I'm trying to get AntD to accept these values as an initial value, but the problem is that it seems that AntD expects a `Date` object, because anytime I try to pass the strings themselves I get an `date.format is not a function` error. I guess that AntD is trying to format the dates, but they're actually strings.

### Code

Next is a minimal example of the problem I'm presenting. If running this with the following dependencies, it produces the error `date.clone is not a function`.

```
import { Form, DatePicker, TimePicker, Input } from "antd";

const initial_data = {
  title: "Title",
  date: "2023-12-05",
  time: "10:23:00"
}

export function Playground() {
  return (
    <Form initialValues={initial_data} >
      <Form.Item name="title" >
        <Input placeholder="Title" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="date" >
        <DatePicker format={"DD/MM/YYYY"} placeholder="Pick a date" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="time" >
        <TimePicker format={"HH:mm"} placeholder="Pick a date" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Dependencies:

- react: 18.2.0
- react-dom: 18.2.0
- antd: 4.24.8

### Things I've tried

For the `DateField` I have no problem, simply I use `moment` to create a `Date` from it. However, I haven't found how to transform the time string "HH:mm:ss" into a `Date` object so that AntD can properly work with it.

Is there a way to do this, or any other idea on how I should work around this issue?

Comment: Hello @JanaL please provide code related to your problem so that we can reproduce problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I included a minimal code example to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antd Datepicker & Timepicker accepts value of type `moment` (Antd v5 uses dayjs instead of moment). For Timepicker, you need to specify the format as second option in moment. `moment('10:23:00', 'HH:mm')`

Since you receive all values from backend and in order to set these values in form, you need to use `useForm` hook.

Here's the complete code that format and sets the values in form.

```
import moment from "moment";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, DatePicker, TimePicker, Input } from "antd";

export function Playground() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get data from backend....
    const response = {
      title: "Title",
      date: "2023-12-05",
      time: "10:23:00",
    };

    form.setFieldsValue({
      ...response,
      date: moment(response.date),
      time: moment(response.time, "HH:mm"),
    });
  }, [form]);

  return (
    <Form form={form}>
      <Form.Item name='title'>
        <Input placeholder='Title' />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name='date'>
        <DatePicker format={"DD/MM/YYYY"} placeholder='Pick a date' />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name='time'>
        <TimePicker format={"HH:mm"} placeholder='Pick a date' />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default Playground;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the `moment(response.time, "HH:mm")` part, and now it works.